# Interpolation in include directive with jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, include, interpolation, pug

Rather self-explanatory, but this is what I'd like to do:

```
- foo = ['elements','here']
include includes/specifications/#{foo.length}
```

It doesn't appear that interpolation is supported, as jade interprets it as a string for an include path.

Comment: If this is Jade you might want to add a tag.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Goofed for a second there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done at this stage in Jade according to the creators:

References: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/569